# How to do AWS S3 object encryption with KMS - CMK from Lambda in .Net

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-kms, aws-sdk-net

I am using Aws SDK (.Net) and trying to create lambda function which needs encrypt an object while uploading to S3 bucket (encryption SSE KMS customer managed key) .

Please help on below queries

1)how can I access the KMS CMK  from lambda c# code?

2. how to use that CMK key in S3 Putobject request serverside encryption type?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the `PutObjectRequest`, set the `serverSideEncryption("aws:kms")` and build the put object request.